# React - Inner functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Imagine a simple form, which renders multiple **custom** components applying some layout tweaks.

The custom components are: `<UsernameInput />`, `<PasswordInput />`, `<DateTimePicker />`, `<FancyButton />`, `<Checkbox />`

And the JSX of the form component looks like:

```
return (
  <View style={globalStyles.flex}>
    <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
      <UsernameInput 
         ... // a lot of props
      />
 
      <PasswordInput 
         ... // a lot of props
      />
   
      <DateTimePicker 
         ... // a lot of props
      />
    </View>

    <View style={styles.footer}>
       <Checkbox />
       <FancyButton type="submit" onPress={...} />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

What if we try to split the component's render method into multiple inner sub-render functions?

```
const LoginForm = ({ ... }) => {
  ...

  /**
   * Renders the inputs of the form.
   *
   * @returns {React.ReactElement} The inputs.
   */
  const renderInputs = () => (
    <View style={styles.inputsContainer}>
      <UsernameInput 
        ... // a lot of props
      />

      <PasswordInput 
        ... // a lot of props
      />

      <DateTimePicker 
        ... // a lot of props
      />
    </View>
  );

  /**
   * Renders the submit button.
   *
   * @returns {React.ReactElement} The footer of the form.
   */
  const renderFooter = () => (
    <View style={styles.footer}>
       <Checkbox />
       <FancyButton type="submit" onPress={...} />
    </View>
  );

  return (
    {renderInputs()}
    {renderFooter()}
  );
};
```

Those helper methods returns JSX! They are not simple vanilla functions, they are components! WE ARE RECREATING COMPONENTS ON EACH RENDER!

In order to handle this, what I do is converting the inner functions to **inner** memoized components, like this:

```
  /**
   * Renders the submit button.
   *
   * @type {React.FC}
   * @returns {React.ReactElement} The footer of the form.
   */
  const Footer = useCallback(() => (
    <View style={styles.footer}>
       <Checkbox />
       <FancyButton type="submit" onPress={...} />
    </View>
  ), [deps]);

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.flex}
      <Inputs />
      <Footer />
    </View>
  );
```

Is this considered an anti-pattern? I mean, should we avoid splitting the JSX when there is no reason to create a new component in the global scope of the app (in a new module or outside the component)?

Comment: It has no sense to me to create a new component called "Inputs" outside the scope of the "Form" component...

Comment: *"They are not simple vanilla functions, they are components! WE ARE RECREATING COMPONENTS ON EACH RENDER!"* Not really, they're just functions that return elements. Recreating functions on every render is common when writing function components with hooks (not that it's necessarily a good idea).

Comment: Recreating the component in the function body of another component is, as you noticed, not such a good pattern. I don't see why you don't want to make separate (new) components at a higher scope. Why is this bad? The module provides a natural place for these components to exist at module-scope w/o being visible to the world. That said, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with memoising the component with `useCallback`.

Comment: If you're still declaring them in the same component (`useCallback` or not), I see no value in splitting them out of the main `return` in the first place. It just takes longer to find the code you need

Comment: I mean, since this is a **function** that returns JSX, wouldn't it be considered a functional component with a lifecycle?

Comment: @VictorioMolina no. You are calling the function yourself, not passing it to React to manage (JSX, `React.createElement`), so they do not have their own lifecycle. The are normal functions that happen to return JSX

Comment: @VictorioMolina - Bizarrely, I *just* answered that question [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658569/react-whats-the-difference-between-a-function-returning-jsx-and-function-compo/71660376#71660376). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and did so very well! This comes up a lot but not usually as the direct question, and it's hard to explain it sufficiently in comments. I'll be saving that one for future reference

Comment: Thanks @BrianThompson! Like most people, I was really confused by it at first (and by `useCallback` in a way similar to the above). Makes it easier to explain when you've been down that road yourself. :-D

Comment: I think you call `useCallback` is not a correct way to memoize, because it just simply remember returned values but the function is still triggered every time (not listening to prop changes). If you want to have correct memo behavior, you can use `React.memo`  instead. It will listen to all your props' changes, if props have no changes, `React.memo` will return the same component (not a function like `useCallback`), but you also need to consider using it for components which you think their computations are expensive. If you overuse it, that will harm your optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this considered an anti-pattern?

There's no point in using `useCallback` on those functions if you don't provide those functions as props to other components that optimize their rendering by not re-rendering when their props don't change. (Lots of people misunderstand `useCallback`, it's a bit subtle.) You're **still** recreating them every time (you have to create the function to pass it into `useCallback`), you're just then doing even more work (processing `deps`) to decide whether to use the newly-created function or the previously-created function. It's overhead without purpose, and not what `useCallback` is for. The purpose of `useCallback` is to create stable or stable-as-possible function references for passing to child components that may be able to avoid re-rendering if you don't change the functions they receive.

Instead, either:

1. Make those components (or just helper functions, depending) in your module. (No need to export them if they're only used by your component.) That way, they're only created **once** (when the module is loaded).

   If you think about it, this is like any other function that's gotten too big: You break it into parts, and put those parts into smaller functions you call. Same concept.

Or

2. Create the functions once, on the first render (ensuring of course that they don't close over anything they need; pass it to them instead), storing the result on an object on a ref via `useRef`:

   ```
   const fnRef = useRef(null);
   if (!fn.Ref.current) {
       fnRef.current = {
            Footer: /*...*/,
            SomethingElse: /*...*/,
            // ...
       };
   }
   const { Footer, SomethingElse /*, ...*/ } = fnRef.current;
   // ...
   ```

   That way, they truly are created only once, on mount.

I would strongly lean toward #1.