# "Rendered fewer hooks than expected", but there are no direct hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I get this error: `Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.`

In itself, this is nothing new to me and I know how to fix this, but I can't figure it out in this case.

```
import reactStringReplace from 'react-string-replace';

import { Entity, Player } from './LogItem';

export default function PrepareText({
  subjects,
  text,
  EntityPill,
  PlayerPill,
}: {
  subjects: { player: Player; entity: Entity };
  text: string;
  EntityPill: (text: string | null) => React.ReactNode;
  PlayerPill: (text: string | null) => React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <>
      {reactStringReplace(text, /(\${\w+})/g, (match, i) => {
        const key = match
          .replace('${', '')
          .replace('}', '') as keyof typeof subjects;

        return (
          <span key={i}>
            {key === 'player'
              ? PlayerPill(subjects[key])
              : EntityPill(subjects[key])}
          </span>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
}
```

I think the problem is with conditionally rendering the two components `PlayerPill` and `EntityPill` because these use hooks inside. But usually, it's not e problem to conditionally render components.

Is it because I call them as functions? Is there e different way to pass props to a `React.ReactNode`?

If there is a better option to do this I would be very excited to implement it.

**Edit**

As requested here is the code of the Pills:

```js
import useSteamUser from '../../../../hooks/useSteamUser';
import { CellProps } from '../LogItem';

export default function TargetCell({ value: text, restricted }: CellProps) {
  return (
    <span className="text-cyan-700 bg-cyan-700/5 px-2 py-0.5 rounded-full border border-cyan-700 text-sm">
      {text}
    </span>
  );
}
```

and these pills are stored in an Object to be dynamically accessed like this:

```js
    NAME_CHANGED: {
      Icon: (
        <GiBodySwapping className="text-3xl fill-sand-500/60 group-hover:fill-sand-500 transition-colors" />
      ),
      text: "You've changed your name!",
      EntityCell: PlayerCell,
      PlayerCell: PlayerCell,
    },
```

Call of PrepareText. My real problem is that I need to pass text to the Pills but the Pills are used in `PrepareText`.

```js
            <PrepareText
              subjects={{
                player: data.player,
                entity: data.entity,
              }}
              text={EVENTS[event].text}
              EntityPill={(text) =>
                EVENTS[event].EntityCell({ value: text || '', restricted })
              }
              PlayerPill={(text) =>
                EVENTS[event].PlayerCell({ value: text || '', restricted })
              }
            />
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because I call them as functions?

Yes. You're not using them as components, you're using them as sub-functions of `PrepareText`. That means they use the component context of `PrepareText`, not their own context. So hooks save information to the underlying `PrepareText` instance, not their own, and so if the number of times you call them varies from render to render, it won't work correctly.

Instead, make them actual components and pass them information as props, not arguments; or make them render components using the arguments you pass them. (See also my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658569/react-whats-the-difference-between-a-function-returning-jsx-and-function-compo).)

Here's an example of passing component functions (`CompA`/`CompB`, passed as `Sub1`/`Sub2`) to another component (`Example`) that uses them conditionally based on a 50/50 coin flip:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const flipCoin = () => Math.random() < 0.5;

const CompA = ({text}) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter(c => c + 1);
        }, 800);
    }, []);
    return <div>CompA, {text}, counter = {counter}</div>;
};

const CompB = ({text}) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter(c => c + 1);
        }, 800);
    }, []);
    return <div>CompB, {text}, counter = {counter}</div>;
};

const Example = ({Sub1, Sub2}) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    return <div>
        <input type="button" value="Re-render" onClick={() => setCounter(c => c + 1)} />
        {flipCoin() && <Sub1 text="a" />}
        {flipCoin() && <Sub2 text="b" />}
    </div>;
};

const App = () => {
    return <Example Sub1={CompA} Sub2={CompB} />;
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

The components use hooks so that you can see that it works just fine that `Example` doesn't always render them when it renders (because of the `flipCoin` calls).

Comment: Im not sure how I would do that in my case because I need to get the pill out of an Object then add the arguments and then again pass the howl thing to ``PrepareText`. I have edited my question and added this code as well. Thx for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm confused: why don't you simply do this:

```js
return (
   <span key={i}>
      {key === 'player'
          ? <PlayerPill text={subjects[key]}/>
          : <EntityPill text={subjects[key]}/>
      }
   </span>
);
```

Comment: Because they're clearly not written as components.

Comment: But the are used like that, so refactore they as needed

Comment: No, they *aren't* used like that, which is (part of) the problem.

Comment: Can you post the code of one of them?

Comment: I'm not the OP.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OP even refers to them as components. This seems like the obvious solution. Not sure what your objection is.

Comment: @super - They clearly aren't components. They're not being used as components, and they don't accept props the way components do. Just turning around and calling them like components **won't work** (assuming, of course, that they accept arguments as shown in the question). The answer is to both use them as components **and** author them as components.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How do you know that? A functional component is a function, and a component. So maybe OP is just confused.

Comment: @super - I'm giving the OP the benefit of the doubt that they're calling their functions as authored, not least as they appear to be running as expected (though of course, not *working* correctly). Occam's Razor. But whatever, I don't think a discussion here is of any use to the OP.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The discussion is for your benefit. :-)

Comment: I have posted the code of the Pills. :)